# how to update OneToOneField of django'user

Tags: django, foreign-keys, one-to-one, relation

I'm using the real django user.
In my project my user can create multiple warriors.
When I want to play I have to choose one of it.

So here is what my class looks like:

```
class Warrior:
    nom = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    ...

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    warrior = models.ForeignKey(Warrior)
```

in my view, I want to change the actual warrior I'm playing with:

```
warrior = get_object_or_404(Warrior, id=id)
request.user.profile.warrior = warrior
```

But that code doesn't work. I think I have an error somewhere
.

Comment: Did you save `profile`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
request.user.profile.warrior = warrior
request.user.profile.save()
```